How to cycle through different internal windows in Android Studio, including emulator
I have the latest patch of AndroidStudio Iguana, on MacOS (latest Sonoma) and I'm struggling using my keyboard shortcuts to cycle through the IDE's windows.
Basically, if I have two instances of Android Studio running in parallel, that's fine, I can go back and forth between them in the same way I can do it with my browser's windows when multiple windows are open.
Yet, if I decide to undock the emulator window, it sticks on top of the rest until I manually click the "- (Reduce)" top right button.
I guess that's an IntelliJ issue, but I remember being able to cycle between the Emulator and the rest in the past.

I found out a way to go back to the ancient days.
In Android Studio -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator, I unchecked the following box: Launch in the Running Devices tool window

I am moderately happy with this solution, because the two windows can't sit together on the same MacOS Desktop if Android Studio is in Full Screen mode. But at least, it's not worse than in the past.

Probably, what you need is a shortcut for "Focus editor" command


Thanks. while the focus is triggered by the shortcut, it does not change the "Always on Top" behavior. Plus, I wouldn't have the same shortcut to go back to the emulator window.
